# iAd Producer checkbox radio buttons?

Tags: checkbox, radio-button, iad, dashcode, producer

I'm new to iAd Producer - what I'm really looking for is a replacement for Dashcode, since Apple seems to have abandoned it. But while it looks as though iAd Producer CAN produce iBooks Author widgets, it seems to be missing a few fundamental objects - namely checkboxes and radio buttons.

I'm sure there's a way to hack HTML and perhaps use jQuery to get the job done, but this was a relatively simple, straightforward thing in Dashcode. Am I missing something? With tools like buttons, sliders, and such, I'd think checkboxes and radio buttons would be included.

Anybody know an EASY way to replicate Dashcode functionality in iAdProducer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny... we seem to be working on the same issue at the same time. Closest I've got to a solution is to build in iAd Producer using the HTML template. There you can add in the objects that are missing using HTML code while also adding drag and drop objects available in the software.

However, while I can populate my view with checkboxes and get them to be checked in iAd Producer's preview, when I preview on my iPad, I can't check the boxes. Radio buttons remain unresponsive too.

Comment: another (less than ideal) option would be to use CSS to draw the objects you want and have them respond to touch events which change their class

Answer (score 1):

I've had the exact same problem for the last week and finally came across a solution. You can "escape" the checkboxes in a way by including an empty onclick property to the checkbox or label that you want to affect. This should override native code that relates to cut-and-paste gestures and make checkboxes unusable. I've had success with this in iBooks Widget Tester.